# Serializing raw values from postgres in a custom django field

Tags: python, django, django-models, julian-date

I'm trying to create a custom field to be able to store BC dates in my database. It will take a Julian Date tuple as input and convert this to a JDN through the jdcal lib. The issue is that python's built-in datetime module doesn't support BC dates, so I cannot parse db values through it. I think I've gotten my field to save correctly, but I'm not sure how to serialize a raw postgres value into my own representation, probably through a tuple of `(year, month, day)` to keep in line with the jdcal library.

```py
from jdcal import gcal2jd

class JDNField(models.DateField):
  description = "A field to save JDN values as postgres `date` types"

  def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    if value is None:
      return None
    jd = gcal2jd(*value)[0] + gcal2jd(*value)[1] + 0.5
    return f'J{jd}'

  def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
      return None
    return # should it go here?

  def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
    return self.to_python(value)
```

Comment: have you tried storing it in a jsonb field?

Comment: @hancho I'm migrating existing data to this field, so I was hoping to be able to retain as much legacy code as possible that expects a DateField (or date type for our raw SQL functions) in addition to the data in our actual db.